# Does replication with SSL encryption work on MySQL 5.5?

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.5, encryption

I am trying to set up replication with slave on Amazon EC2 and master in our local environment. The setup went fine without SSL encryption. But when I set up the replication to be SSL encrypted, it is failing to connect to Master.

MySQL version on Master : Server version: 5.5.19-log MySQL Community Server (GPL) 
MySQL version on Slave  : Server version: 5.5.14-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)

I have SSL encrypted replication set up and going fine where the Master's MySQL version is Server version: 5.1.56-log Source distribution. But it is failing for the other Master machine which has MySQL 5.5.

So my question is, does SSL encrypted replication work for MySQL 5.5?

Anyone here faced the same problem? Please throw some light on how to get around this problem. Note that I have changed the permissions for my SSL certificates used in Slave machine to be mysql instead of root (Both failed anyway)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To use SSL for encrypting the transfer of the binary log required during replication, both the master and the slave must support SSL network connections. If either host does not support SSL connections (because it has not been compiled or configured for SSL), replication through an SSL connection is not possible.

Setting up replication using an SSL connection is similar to setting up a server and client using SSL. You must obtain (or create) a suitable security certificate that you can use on the master, and a similar certificate (from the same certificate authority) on each slave.

For more information on setting up a server and client for SSL connectivity [refer this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/secure-using-ssl.html)

Please follow the steps mentioned here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-solutions-ssl.html

I was searching in bugs.mysql.com related to MySQL 5.5 but there is nothing reported w.r.t "replication with SSL" for v5.5.
You can mention exact error message here for analysis.